# How to display image inside web form from Byte Array with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is my code, all it does is clear the web page and draw the image, so the rest of the form disappears! I need to show the image inside the form.

This is my User Control to display the images:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["ObjHoteles"] == null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Por favor, primero seleccione un hotel para desplegar las fotos.";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Byte[]> ArrayFotos = new List<Byte[]>();
                string NombreDelHotel = "";

                Hoteles Hotel1 = (Hoteles)Session["ObjHoteles"];
                NombreDelHotel = Hotel1.NombreHotel;

                ArrayFotos = Persistencia.PersistenciaFotos.FotosDeHotel(NombreDelHotel);
                Session["CantFotos"] = ArrayFotos.Count();

                Byte[] Foto = ArrayFotos[0];

                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Response.Expires = 0;
                Response.BinaryWrite(Foto);
                Session["NumFoto"] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                List<Byte[]> ArrayFotos = new List<Byte[]>();
                string NombreDelHotel = "";

                Hoteles Hotel1 = (Hoteles)Session["ObjHoteles"];
                NombreDelHotel = Hotel1.NombreHotel;

                ArrayFotos = Persistencia.PersistenciaFotos.FotosDeHotel(NombreDelHotel);
                Session["CantFotos"] = ArrayFotos.Count();

                Byte[] Foto = ArrayFotos[(int)Session["NumFoto"]];

                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Response.Expires = 0;
                Response.BinaryWrite(Foto);

            }
        }
```

I need to find a way that doesnt clear all the page, just draw the image inside the user control.

Comment: Hmm.. Please revise your question so it will list this specific demand of using a user control to achieve this.. made by your client according to what I read in your comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could write a page .aspx or a handler maybe .ashx that send the content of the picture  back to the browser. You could pass information in the url.
Then use the url to this page with an html tag or html control to display it.

EDIT:
You need to use a Control. You could convert the binary data to base64 and output the content to the html page.

I give you an example with an img html tag:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsMAAAGhCAIAAAALOi7ZAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3QgLEhM6PUSGrwAAIABJREFUeNq8vcuSLEmWHKZ6jnlEZt5761Z3T/eAHAICAYRcEALsuOCWPzbzDfwP/gKXWJACoRDCBSkEBgPhADKY7qnu+4wIdztHuThmHh55q2t6ho+SlpaqyMwID3ez89CjqsY//dM//bM/+zMc/pGE3//PT/z09/1I0t/1Rz/x+o9+0I++vv/n8fU/8MW/9U9+9JVvL/v/u1cy86cv5ttfePXKq//8fTfhp+/qT3/oq8v+6V/+Ay/v25/+4X/46nqO"/>
```

You can also use base64 encoding for image with CSS:

```
background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,IVB)
```

To convert into base64 from C# you can use:

```
using System;
```

and:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Foto);
```

Comment: Hi, my client requested that i use a User Control.

Comment: Could you explain how to do it with CSS and base64 data?

Comment: This will not work with Internet Explorer 7 and earlier, because the data URI scheme is not supported at all and has limited support in Internet Explorer 8; read [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for more information.

Comment: I tried this after converting an image from a byte array to a base64 string. It didn't work until I remove the trailing "2Q==" from the end of the base64 string, then it was fine.

Answer (score 14):

There is also another simple way:

1. On your `.aspx` page:

   ```
   <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"></asp:Image>
   ```
2. Then in your CodeBehind file `.aspx.cs`:

   ```
   Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Foto)
   ```

Comment: Used this for my web application and it worked a treat. I wouldn't worry too much about IE7 and below as mentioned in previous comments. Most users will have IE8 and above or chrome/firefox etc... most people use the latest versions of available browsers now. Shire +1

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Clear();` is deleting all the buffered content (i.e. everything in your page).

Instead of a user control to display a dynamic image, consider an HTTP handler (`.ashx`), like this:

ImageHandler.ashx:

```
public class ImageHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Logic to get byte array here
        byte[] buffer = WhateverLogicNeeded;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Then in your `.aspx` page:

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImageHandler.ashx" />
```

Note: If you want a specific image, then you can pass a query string (i.e. image ID) to the handler and have the byte array logic account for using the query string value.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for your answer! My client requested specifically that i use a user control!