# create an image from a byte array using javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, arrays, web-worker

At the moment I use a generic - ASHX - handler (that is called via ajax/jquery) to load an image into an IMG element like so...

```
serverimage1x4.src = '/Cloud/LiveXP.ashx';
```

However, instead of this I would like a web worker to do this.

I am returning a byte array from a web worker and using 'postmessage' it back to the parent UI.

So, assuming I use a XMLHttpRequest to return a byte array to the UI how do I load that byte array into an Image/IMG element?

Would I be better of trying to load a canvas element instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display image inside web form from Byte Array with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177351/how-to-display-image-inside-web-form-from-byte-array-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi, it is NOT a duplicate. I am using JavaScript not C# I need the equivalent of to C#

Comment: The accepted answer to that question answers your question as well...

Comment: actually i am too trigger happy here.  My question states I already have a byte array. I wanted to know how to convert to an image using javascript.  Using base64 on client side will inflate the image size. but thanks anyway

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the way to do it. I wouldn't worry about "inflation" unless it's either extremely big images or extremely puny client devices.

Comment: Hi assaf. OK, if accept that I would still want to process it on the client.  I have the byte array on the client and I am just trying to load/display it as an image. That link you kindly gave me I have most of that code in my existing ashx page. Because I am now looking at using web workers I am now working with byte arrays within the client.  If I can load it as an image I would be happy. Else I might as well stick to what I got...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. The answer given shows you how to display the image that you have received as an array of bytes.

Comment: hi, those answer relate to server side processing and I am looking at client side processing.  This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976327/binary-array-to-canvas gives me the closest to what I was looking for but I need to to undertsand whether the byte array I have is a TypedArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`putImageData()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=putimagedata).

Here's a usage example which arbitrarily modifies an existing canvas by manipulating a byte array:

```
  var image=draw.getImageData(0,0,W,H), data=image.data;
  for ( var y=0; y<H; y++ ) for ( var x=0; x<W; x++ )
    {
    var index=(x+y*W)*4;
    data[0+index]=x+y; // red
    data[1+index]=x; // green
    data[2+index]=255-data[2+index]; // blue
    data[3+index]=255; // alpha
    }
  draw.putImageData(image,0,0);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. So, image.data would be my byte array? Also, by enumerating through will it not incur a delay in displaying an image? I am wanting to refresh the image as quick as possible you see. I will test this though 1st - thank you

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: In the simplest case, you would acquire `image.data` from the existing canvas as I have done here.  You can then copy your byte array based on the example indexing that I have shown (replace my arbitrary changes with something that copies pixels from your byte array).  I don't know about the speed -- it will probably be browser dependent.

Comment: HI, this is all very informative and thanks for it. Will be testing it ASAP and will post back - thanks