# How to upload images to mysql database using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert an image from windows application to mysql database . while trying to do so i have encountered the following error

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type'System.IConvertible'."

```
public void LoadImages()          
{        
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);        
    cn.Open();    
    string image = txtLogo.Text;    
    byte[] ImageData;    
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);    
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);    
    ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);    
    br.Close();    
    fs.Close();    
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into Fn_Pictures(Images,Email)values(@Images,'"+txtEmailId.Text+"')", cn);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Images", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = ImageData;    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    cn.Close();    
}
```

Please help in clearing this error.

Comment: At witch line the error happens?

Comment: When i debugged the code error is shown at executenonquerry(;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into Fn_Pictures(Images,Email)values(?Images,'" + txtEmailIdText + "')", cn);

MySqlParameter parImage = new MySqlParameter();
parImage.ParameterName = "?Images";
parImage.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.MediumBlob;
parImage.Size = 3000000;
parImage.Value = ImageData;//here you should put your byte []

cmd.Parameters.Add(parImage);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This could be one way to check if the Image has been stored to db

```
//write your code to get the record from db to byte[] ImageData;
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteBLOBData )
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData );
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

call like this

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
picture.Image = byteArrayToImage(ImageData);
Controls.Add(picture);
```

Comment: When you get it out you must process the bytes and show them as image

Comment: Depends what kind of application you are doing WPF WinForm ASP.NET?

Comment: ASP.NET (C#) its windows application

Comment: This should help you decide how to proceed on showing the Image 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177351/how-to-display-image-inside-web-form-from-byte-array-with-c-sharp.   As about the Writing the image to the database I think you have the answer

Comment: @user3531533 How do you know that it isn't?

Comment: when i have checked the table in my database the particular image column has no entry nothing but "BLOB"

Comment: blob stands for byte[] which is the actual image please try to make your view image first to check that the image is stored in the db

Comment: K then as u have seen my code both email id and image must be stored in that particular table but emailid column is just empty.....

Comment: I dont know how to do that...?

Comment: Its windows appp not web app Its written in C#

Comment: @user3531533 this is what you said : _ASP.NET (C#) its windows application –  user3531533 1 hour ago_

Comment: To you Windows App means Windows 8 App? or Windows Application like WinForms or WPF

Comment: This is getting messy. 
What type of project did you create?
Post some code of your view add more details.

Comment: I guess you have WinForms Application