# ASP.net- Dropdown list to gridview With Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, aspxgridview

Please Help me to solve my problem .. 
I want to **retrieve my images** in gridview which stores in database with ***image datatype***.
i am newbie so please help me..

```
SqlConnection conn;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adp;
string str;
string strCon = "Data Source=S-PC;Initial Catalog=SA;Integrated Security=True";
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    str = "SELECT imgg from SA_Stock where '"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+"";
    conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    cmd=new SqlCommand(str,conn);
    adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["SA_Stock"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Thanking you for your help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try tto get the reference of image control in onrowdatabound event and  load the byte array from sql to control. see link below

[How to display image inside web form from Byte Array with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177351/how-to-display-image-inside-web-form-from-byte-array-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you for your reply..
But i have to link it with my gridview control dynamically..

Comment: From the posted code it gives a feel that GridView1 is defined in the mark up. if so then what are you referring to when saying building dynamically.

Comment: Thank you mate for your concern i solved my issue ..
and it is ".cs" code.